# SSIS Excel Dump not dumping integer values

Tags: ssis

I have a excel source and I am dumping the excel to OLE DB Destination. The excel has a column M4. The corresponding data type in the db is `nvarchar`. All the column values will be dumped to db except the one with value 927. Means integer value is not dumped other values are of varchar type. How to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

In your DFT, apply 'Data Conversion' on your column M4. Set the datatype of output column to 'Unicode string[DT_WSTR]'. Instead of inserting data from M4 column, use the new column for inserting your data.

Comment: What error are you getting? A little more detail would help!

Comment: @Manoj if you can provide a bit more details of your issue, i could look into the issue more

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link that soved problem.
http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/dbprogramming/mssqlserver/what-s-the-deal-with/